AOS CSS animation does not work on scroll
I use the AOS CSS library for scroll animation, but now it works immediately when the page loads. How to fix it?


jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  //AOS CSS
  AOS.init({});
  
})

    <div class="counter-section--content">
    <?php if (!empty($counter_item)):
      $delay = 200;
      foreach ($counter_item as $item):
        $counter_item_color = $item['counter_item_color'];
        $counter_item_icon = $item['counter_item_icon'];
        $counter_item_number = $item['counter_item_number'];
        $counter_item_text = $item['counter_item_text'];
        ?>
                  <div class="counter-section--content-item" data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-delay="<?= $delay; ?>" data-aos-duration="1500">
                    <div class="content-item--icon" style="background-color: <?= $counter_item_color; ?>;">
                      <img src="<?= $counter_item_icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?= $counter_item_icon['alt']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-item--text">
                      <div class="content-item--text-counter">
                      <span class="counter" data-count="<?= $counter_item_number; ?>">0</span>
                      <span class="plus">+</span>
                      </div>
                      <p><?= $counter_item_text; ?></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            <?php
            $delay += 100;
      endforeach;
    endif; ?>
    </div>



in the example, the second section of the site is provided, but its animation runs immediately when the page loads and not when you scroll to it.
I connect the files this way:


    wp_enqueue_style('aos-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/libs/aos.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('aos-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/libs/aos.js', array('jquery'), false, true);




you can try to disable AOS initialization on page load and instead trigger it only when the element is scrolled into view.

I found the reason. Even addEventListener "scroll" did not work on my site because the body had height: 100%. This is such a strange thing)
